# How to simplify two functions that similar with each other

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm a student studying computer engineering.
today I was learning quick sort using C++.
It is so awesome algorithm and I recognized that quick sort needs 
two function for ascending order and the opposite.
Following is my codes!

```
#include <iostream>
#define ASCENDING 0 
#define DESCENDING 1
#define MAX_SIZE 50001

using namespace std;


int numberCnt;
int sortManner;
int list[MAX_SIZE];

void GetInput();
void QuickSort(int* list, int left, int right, int(*partition)(int*, int, int));
int PartitionAscending(int* list, int left, int right);
int PartitionDescending(int* list, int left, int right);
void Swap(int &a, int &b);

int main(){
    GetInput();
    QuickSort(list, 0, numberCnt - 1, sortManner == ASCENDING ? PartitionAscending : PartitionDescending);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberCnt; i++){
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void QuickSort(int* list, int left, int right, int (*partition)(int*,int,int)){
    if (left < right){
        int pivot = partition(list, left, right);
        QuickSort(list, left, pivot - 1, partition);
        QuickSort(list, pivot + 1, right, partition);
    }
}
int PartitionAscending(int* list, int left, int right){
    int pivotVal = list[left];
    int pivotIdx = left;
    int low = left;
    int high = right + 1;

    do{
        do{
            low++;
        } while (list[low] < pivotVal);
        do{
            high--;
        } while (list[high] > pivotVal);
        if (low < high)
            Swap(list[low], list[high]);
    } while (low < high);

    Swap(list[pivotIdx], list[high]);

    return high;
}

int PartitionDescending(int* list, int left, int right){
    int pivotVal = list[left];
    int pivotIdx = left;
    int low = left;
    int high = right + 1;

    do{
        do{
            low++;
        } while (list[low] > pivotVal);
        do{
            high--;
        } while (list[high] < pivotVal);
        if (low < high)
            Swap(list[low], list[high]);
    } while (low < high);

    Swap(list[pivotIdx], list[high]);

    return high;
}

void Swap(int &a, int &b){
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void GetInput(){
    cin >> numberCnt >> sortManner;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberCnt; i++)
        cin >> list[i];
}
```

You know the functions is very similar with each other!
It seems that wasteful to me!

How to simplify the functions?

If you don't understand my pool English
Plz, don't hesitate to let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

Your partition can take a comparison functor, something like:

```
template <typename Comp>
int Partition(int* list, int left, int right, Comp comp){
    int pivotVal = list[left];
    int pivotIdx = left;
    int low = left;
    int high = right + 1;

    do{
        do{
            low++;
        } while (comp(list[low], pivotVal));
        do{
            high--;
        } while (!comp(list[high], pivotVal));
        if (low < high)
            Swap(list[low], list[high]);
    } while (low < high);

    Swap(list[pivotIdx], list[high]);

    return high;
}

int PartitionAscending(int* list, int left, int right){
    return Partition(list, left, right, [](int l, int r){ return l < r; });
    // or return Partition(list, left, right, std::less<int>());
}

int PartitionDescending(int* list, int left, int right){
    return Partition(list, left, right, [](int l, int r){ return l > r; });
    // or return Partition(list, left, right, std::greater<int>());
}
```

Comment: I would simplify the functions into one as given in this answer but also keep `PartitionAscending`/`PartitionDescending` as functions themselves just make them call the general `Partition` function with the correct `comp` value - makes it immediately obvious in the code as to which you are calling

Comment: I apologise, you've just added my point to your answer already :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an other argument to your function that would specify if you need a ascending or descending call, a boolean `ascending` can do that, and calculate the loop condition like this :

```
do{
   low++;
} while ( ascending ? (list[low] < pivotVal) : (list[low] > pivotVal));
```